# Scrapy: Why extracted strings are in this format?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm doing

```
item['desc'] = site.select('a/text()').extract()
```

but this will be printed like this

```
[u'\n                    A mano libera\n                  ']
```

What must I do to tim and remove strange chars like [u'\n , the traling space and '] ?

I cannot trim (strip)

```
exceptions.AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

and if converting to string and then stripping, the result was the string above, which I suppose to be in UTF-8

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The html page may very well contains these whitespaces characters.

What you retrieve a **list** of unicode strings, which is why you can't simply call `strip` on it. If you want to strip these whitespaces characters from *each* string in this list, you can run the following:

```
>>> [s.strip() for s in [u'\n                    A mano libera\n                  ']]
[u'A mano libera']
```

If only the first element matters to you, than simply do:

```
>>> [u'\n                    A mano libera\n                  '][0].strip()
u'A mano libera'
```

Comment: Please, can you edit to show me how to set the result to a variable ? I cannot 'strip' the result of extract() !

Comment: Wow ! You found the problem:: **It was a list**, so using `item['desc'] = str(site.select('a/text()').extract()[0]).strip();` I've got what I need !

Answer (score 9):

There's a nice solution to this using [Item Loaders](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.16/topics/loaders.html). Item Loaders are objects that get data from responses, process the data and build Items for you. Here's an example of an Item Loader that will strip the strings and return the first value that matches the XPath, if any:

```
from scrapy.contrib.loader import XPathItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import MapCompose, TakeFirst

class MyItemLoader(XPathItemLoader):
    default_item_class = MyItem
    default_input_processor = MapCompose(lambda string: string.strip())
    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()
```

And you use it like this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    loader = MyItemLoader(response=response)
    loader.add_xpath('desc', 'a/text()')
    return loader.load_item()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
desc = site.select('a/text()').extract()
desc=[s.strip() for s in desc]
item['desc']=desc[0]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. (This answer got into the 'Low Quality Posts' queue ;) .. )

Comment: @FirstOne : I am not agree with your reply maximum user on stackover flow they only want exact answer